# infura HTTP method GET not allowed

Tags: javascript, hardhat, ipfs-http-client, x-ipfs-path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXX9p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOWGP.png)

above two errors show the detail.

```
/* create-item.js */

import { useState } from 'react'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

const client = ipfsHttpClient('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0')

import {
  nftaddress, nftmarketaddress  
} from '../config'

import NFT from '../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json'
import Market from '../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json'

export default function CreateItem () {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null)
  const [formInput, updateFormInput] = useState({ price: '', name: '', description: '' })
  const router = useRouter()

  async function onChange(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    try {
      const added = await client.add(
        file,
        {
          progress: (prog) => console.log('received: ${prog}')
        }
      )
      const url = 'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}'
      setFileUrl(url)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)  
    }
  }
  
  async function createItem() {
    const { name, description, price } = formInput
    if (!name || !description || !price || !fileUrl) return
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      name, description, image: fileUrl
    })

    try {
      const added = await client.add(date)
      const url = 'https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}'
      /* */
      createSale(url)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file: ', error)
    }
  }

  async function createSale() {
    const Web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()

    let contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, signer)
    let transaction = await contract.createToken(url)
    let tx = await transaction.wait()

    let event = tx.events[0]
    let value = event.args[2]
    let tokenId = value.toNumber()

    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, 'ether')

    contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer)
    let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

    transaction = await contract.createMarketItem(
      nftaddress, tokenId, price, { value: listingPrice }
    )
    await transaction.wait()
    router.push('/')
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
        <input
          placeholder="Asset Name"
          className="mt-8 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <textarea
          placeholder="Asset Description"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, description: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Asset Price in Matic"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, price: e.target.value })}
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          name="Asset"
          className='my-4'
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        {
          fileUrl && (
            <img className="rounded mt-4" width="350" src={fileUrl} />
          )
        }
        <button
          onClick={createItem}
          className="font-bold mt-4 bg-pink-500 text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg"
        >
          Create Digital Asset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}
```

I gusss my infura is wrong with the setup.

issue:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

I tried to setup projectID and the secret key from infura, but it did not work.

expect:

1. it seems they are already on v3 - I should move this
2. the error (and the docs) suggests that I am using GET - change to POST

reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKJBEEXUha0

However, I lost how I setup that. Could anybody suggest any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the project id that infura.io requires the first screenshot returns that.

Following the [sample request](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ipfs/http-api-methods/add) provided by infura.io, an Authorization header is required when a request sent, you might need to re-implement your ipfsHttpClient with the following code.

Also, there's a bug reported in older ipfs-http-client that can't pass the Authorization header properly but has been fixed in [v44.0.1](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/issues/3063#issuecomment-638709726), make sure you're using the latest version of this package as well.

For the second screenshot, `/api/v0/add` is a POST method that is defined by infura.io, paste the URL into your browser result to trigger a GET method

```js
const client = ipfsHttpClient({
    host: 'https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0',
    headers: {
                Authorization:
                    'Your infura token here'
            }
})
```

Comment: After entering PROJECT ID from PROJECT SUMMARY in authorization, the error appeared again. (POST http://https:3000/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED), error seems still error..I am trying to do my best. Thank you so much for solving this.

Comment: Depending on your comment, looks like ipfsHttpClient didn't treat the host parameter well, maybe you need to look into ipfs-http-client document to figure it out.